# Let $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $\tau$ be a finite complement topology. Is the funtion $f: X\to X$ defined by $f(x)=x^2$ continuous?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> Let $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $\tau$ be a finite complement topology. Is the funtion $f: X\to X$ defined by  $f(x)=x^2$ continuous?

---

I think it is continuous. Because the open sets of $\mathbb{R}$ with respect to finite complement topology are infinite. I am not exactly sure, can anyone help me?

Comment: Yes, it is continuous.

Comment: Are you putting the cofinite topology on both the domain of definition and the target?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you consider the finite complement (a.k.a. cofinite) topology on both the domain and the codomain.

A subset $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ in the cofinite topology is closed if and only if $A$ is either finite or $A=\mathbb{R}$.

Now clearly $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}$. And so the question boils down to: if $A$ is a finite set then is $f^{-1}(A)$ finite as well? And this, on the other hand, translates to the algebraic question: if $p\in\mathbb{R}[X]$ is a polynomial, then how many solutions $p(X)=0$ has (also note that the preimage of union is the union of preimages)? The answer is always finite. In particular $f$ is continuous.

Note that not every classical function will be continuous in the cofinite topology. For example $f(x)=\sin(x)$ is not continuous, because $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is infinite.